# VbScript-how to use array variable in the the program?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I create code like this

```
a=Array(-fx,-cr,-ie)

Set iim1= CreateObject ("imacros")

    i = iim1.iimInit("a(0)", true)
    iret = iim1.iimInit()
    iret = iim1.iimSet("row", m)
    iret = iim1.iimPlay("hiren")
    iret = iim1.iimExit()

End Function
```

I define the array at a=Array(-fx,-cr,-ie).
now i use this array like a(0) in the code like i use here

i = iim1.iimInit("a(0)", true).
but it is not working plz help.
what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`a(0)` is your first array element. `"a(0)"` is just a string. Try removing the quotes.

Also, `iimInit()` requires a string for its first parameter. So you need to add quotes to your array elements during definition.

```
a = Array("-fx", "-cr", "-ie")

Set iim1 = CreateObject("imacros")
i = iim1.iimInit(a(0), True)    ' a(0) is the string "-fx"
```

Comment: I've never used iMacros before but, from looking at their doc page, it looks like the first param to `iimInit()` should be a string. So your array definition should look like this: `a = Array("-fx", "-cr", "-ie")`

Comment: but for the that the variable should be "-fx" in execution by this it take only -fx as variable..do you know how to " special character as variable.this will solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Did changing it to `a = Array("-fx", "-cr", "-ie")` not work? It should.

Comment: I changed the code above to demonstrate what I'm saying. Did you notice you have two `iimInit()` statements in your original code? Also, does it work if you don't use the array and just specify a string literal?